# My website Stuck to the right in IE8, IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i have a problem with IE8 and IE9, my website stuck to the right side of browser, I Can fix that with body: text-align: center; but the problem is that I dont want all my text be aligned center. and its in my localhost so I cant have an online example, I would appreciate it if anyone can help me how to fix this problem. thanks.

Comment: please provide some code & a live example for better understanding

Comment: Yeah, we need an example, but if I read your issue correctly, maybe wrapping your website markup, anything within <body></body>, within a div and then aligning that div according to your needs, you'll overcome to centering of all text and content on your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled a lil more and figured that the problem is because of doctype, I declared a standard doctype and it looks ok now. thanks for replays btw.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your markup...

```
<body>
   <div style="width: 990px; margin: 0 auto;">

   <!-- content of your site -->

    </div>
<body>
```

`margin: 0 auto` is the important part here.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yujYX/

Comment: I have a wrapper inside my body with the same style you mentioned, it displays right in chrome and firefox but in IE it's not centered. and sry it's a long code with lots of styles, so cant have a live example

Comment: @Sohail - do you have a width declared on the wrapper?

Comment: yeah width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Try creating a JS Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) with the relevant parts. It sounds like something in your style is causing a problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i just figured it out, the problem was that I haven't declared doctype properly. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

try to check your css, they should have a fixed width and margin:0 auto;

> body {
>       margin: 0 auto;
>       width: 960px; }